# What is the best way to authenticate a user over IVR?

Tags: security, authentication, asterisk

I am trying to build an IVR system that requires some form of username & password/pin entry to access sensitive data. My naïve solution seemed obvious enough, until I realized that username/pass over a keypad essentially reduces to a long string of digits (0-9) -> [easy to attack](https://i.redd.it/5fhljsxwpzk81.png).

The application is designed to be a sort of fail-safe or safety net in times of emergency, so authentication-over-the-phone is necessary. Plan B is to have the user enter their username using voice and to use the keypad to enter their pin; but I lack the security expertise to judge whether or not this workaround is safe enough for the field, [especially given all of the novel ways to brute-force interfaces these days](https://infocondb.org/con/def-con/def-con-19/brute-forcing-interactive-voice-response-ivr-systems).

How is this typically done in production?

Comment: There is no "typically done in production". What is a sensible level of precaution for some sensitive data ("this is the balance on your account") is very definitely not a sensible level of precaution for other data ("these are the nuclear launch codes").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is:

"enter your customer account number"

"enter the Xth number of your security number,"

"enter the Yth number of your security number"

with a 3 attempt lockout after which you have to talk to a human.

Obviously if you can try a hundred times, this is not very secure at all. But the slowness of the entry method and the low number cut off and need for human reactivation (and choosing a new security number) makes it practically hard to do.

Ultimately these things are not very secure. But the bar is very low when you consider the alternative social engineering hacks, phoning a human and saying you forgot your password is super insecure.